# Display style proofs using Coq

Tags: coq, beginner, proof-tree

How to display proofs using in Gentzen tree style and (or) Fitch-style, using CoqIDE or JsCoq?

PS: I'm rookie used coq.

Comment: I edited the tags and created the [proof-tree] tag, feel free to edit if you feel this is inaccurate

Comment: There is [prooftree](http://askra.de/software/prooftree/)

Comment: The proofweb is perfect!!! I found picture of proofweb, but has discontinued and no longer has an installation script.